# Kendoui databind with Jquery datasource not working

Tags: jquery, json, kendo-ui

Hi I'm trying to bind data to a kendochart, but no bars are appearing on the chart. If I get the url in a web browser, the following string is returned.

```
[{"AreaName":"Rondebosch","NumberOfIncidents":2}, {"AreaName":"Claremont","NumberOfIncidents":2}, {"AreaName":"Athlone","NumberOfIncidents":2}]
```

The code is as follows

```
var Reports = {};
    $.ajax({
        url: "Home/getIncidentPerArea",
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (json) {
            Reports = json;
            $("#Chart").kendoChart({ title: { text: "Incidents Per Area" },
                DataSource: {
                    data: Reports
                },
                series: [{ name: "Incidents Per Area", field:"NumberOfIncidents"}]
        });
    }
});
```

Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dataSource option is spelled in Camel case.

In addition, the [data source](http://www.kendoui.com/documentation/dataviz/chart/configuration.aspx#dataSource) can request the data directly:

```
dataSource: {
    transport: {
        read: "Home/getIncidentPerArea"
    }
}
```